# pthread_cond_wait does not unlock the mutex

Tags: c++, c, multithreading, macos, pthreads

In the first place, my problem is different.

In my scenario, there is one waiting thread, which waits on condition variable. Signalling thread signals conditional variable.

My code is

```
//Wating thread

//Lock the mutex_
//mutex_ is of pthread_mutex_t  and is initialized.
result = pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex_);
assert(result == 0);

do {
    //Wait on condition variable cvar_
    //cva_ is of pthread_cond_t  and is initialized.
    result = pthread_cond_wait(&cvar_, &mutex_);  //POINT 1
}while(result == 0 && !state_);

//Unlock the mutex_.
result = pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex_);

//signalling thread
result = pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex_); //POINT 2
assert(result == 0);
state_ = 1;
result = pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex_);
assert(result == 0);

//signals the condition variable.
pthread_cond_signal(&cvar_);
```

My operating system is Mac OS X 10.8 but minimum target is 10.6
This is running fine without any problem in almost every cases except one.

In a particular case, I notices that after POINT 1 that is `pthread_cond_wait`, mutex_ is not unlocked when it enters into wait state. This I confirmed by `pthread_mutex_trylock` which returns EBUSY in this case. And due to this, signalling thread goes into wait and ultimately results in a deadlock.

I would like to know under what condition, `pthread_cond_wait` does not unlock the mutex passed to it. What is the cause of this problem?

Comment: `pthread_cond_wait` always unlocks the mutex passed, and it does so atomically w.r.t. waiting on the condition variable; when it returns, it atomically locks the mutex again w.r.t. the thread running again.  Any code on either side of the `pthread_cond_wait` is going to observe the mutex in the locked state.

Comment: Please show the `pthread_mutex_trylock()` loop code. There might be an issue with that code.

Comment: @AdamRosenfield: You are right. But in a particular case, I observed this problem.
jxh: I am using pthread_mutex_trylock in debugger, not in code.

Comment: Are you sure you properly initialized the mutex? If the `mutex_` variable holds garbage, the behavior of the functions is undefined.

Comment: Oh, and you shouldn't use a do-while loop. You need to check `state_` *before* waiting on the condition (and don't wait if the condition is already satisfied) because the other thread may already have signaled it and you'll wait forever (because nothing else will ever signal it again).

Comment: How do you know your debugger has stopped both threads in such a way that the signalling thread has not acquired the lock after the `pthread_cond_wait()`?

Comment: @KenThomases: Mutex is initialized. This is done inside the constructor.

Comment: @jxh Before signalling thread acquires mutex_, I checked it in debugger using pthread_mutex_trylock() and it returns EBUSY.

Comment: Thank you everyone. I added the answer. Please solve my doubt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading about [pthread_setcancelstate](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/System/Conceptual/ManPages_iPhoneOS/man3/pthread_setcancelstate.3.html), I found that `pthread_cond_wait` is a cancellation point of the thread. If cancel is enabled for the thread and is deferred, then cancellation point will test for cancel. If any cancel is pending, thread will exit.

So, in my case, thread exits leaving mutex_ locked. Therefore signalling thread blocks.

But there is one more doubt. All the threads are being created from the same function using Thread class. Why only this thread has got such behaviour of cancellation?

Answer (score 1):

As @KenThomases pointed out: your problem is that you are missing the signal, not that the signal isn't getting sent.  The signalling thread is calling `pthread_cond_signal()` *before* the waiting thread calls `pthread_cond_wait()`.  `pthread_cond_wait()` should only be called *after* you've tested that the invariants you are looking for aren't currently met:

```
while (!state_) {
  result = pthread_cond_wait(&cvar_, &mutex_);
  if (result == EINVAL) ... // error handling
}
```

The other thing that can help sometimes is to put the signalling thread's call to `pthread_cond_signal()` inside the critical section.  This isn't necessary to fix your problem, but can make the program easier to reason about because you know that no-one else is holding the mutex at the time you signal them:

```
// signalling thread
...
result = pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex_);
...
state_ = 1;
//signals the condition variable.
pthread_cond_signal(&cvar_);
result = pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex_);
...
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. While debugging, I found that waiting thread is entering into wait before signalling thread signals. Later, I found that actually waiting thread exits on pthread_cond_wait() therefore leaving mutex_ locked. I will soon post more on this.